# Get all process PID's and pass them to program.exe as an argument

Tags: powershell

I want to enumerate every process in memory, get its PID, and pass them to `program.exe` as an argument.

I'm getting in the ballpark with:

```
Get-Process | ForEach-Object {Start-Process "powershell" ./myprogram.exe -command $_.ID}
```

However, this isn't correct as I receive the error:

> A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'command'

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  The issue is that you are not passing the parameters to `Start-Process` correctly - they should be either a single string or an array of strings.  Have a look at the [help for Start-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-6) for some examples of its use.

Comment: Well the parameter needs to be the id variable. Still need quotes?

Comment: Not really, but the problem isn't just that you aren't quoting `$_.ID`, but that the whole call to Start-Process doesn't make sense.  it seems like you are trying to launch PowerShell and another exe at the same time, or some other odd action.  Are you trying to launch `.\myprogram.exe` and pass the ID to it as a parameter?  If so, then you need to call it like this:  `Start-Process -FilePath "myprogram.exe" -ArgumentList $_.ID`.  The reference to `PowerShell` and `-Command` are not needed.

Comment: exactly, Your line would work with 
    `Get-Process | ForEach-Object {Start-Process ./myprogram.exe $_.ID}`
If Your program accepts default parameter . if You have to do something like .\myprogram -PID $_.id  
Do something like 
`Get-Process | ForEach-Object {Start-Process ./myprogram.exe "-PID $($_.ID)"}`

Comment: @boxdog add you comment as an answer as it's the correct solution here.

Comment: @JamesC. Added.

Answer (score 1):

Your call to `Start-Process` doesn't make sense. It seems like you are trying to launch PowerShell and another .exe at the same time, or some other odd action.

If you are you trying to launch `.\myprogram.exe` and pass the ID to it as a parameter, then you need to call it like this:

```
Start-Process -FilePath ".\myprogram.exe" -ArgumentList $_.ID
```

The reference to PowerShell and `-Command` are not needed.

As @Tomek points out, you  may need to include some other parameter for the target .exe itself, like this:

```
Start-Process -FilePath ".\myprogram.exe" -ArgumentList "-PID $($_.ID)"
```